# What do the numbers next to the recipes in the crafting window mean?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In my crafting window there are numbers next to all the items I can make, but I don't know what they mean.  I initially thought it was how many I could make with stuff I had on hand, but in my screenshot I can clearly make 3 when it says 0.  Is it bugged or does it mean something else entirely?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those figures are supposed to show how many of the item you can make, I believe the fault you have pointed out is because of the systems inability to differentiate between your characters inventory, and yoru cargo hold inventory :S

Additionally the intensity of the colour indicates how much of a boost the item will give the crafting skill when made:

- grey ( + 0 pt )
- green ( + 1 pt per 2 items made )
- yellow ( + 1 pt per item made )
- orange ( +2 pt pre item made ) ~VMT to sarge-smith, and mufasa for this information~

It might be worth popping into the devtracker forum and letting them know about this.

Comment: The color indicates the level compared to your max. So gray won't help you level the skill at all. Green a little, yellow more, orange the most.

Comment: specifically, green increases your skill level 1 pt/2 made. yellow 1pt/1 made. and orange 2pt/1made.

Answer (score 2):

They're supposed to represent how many you can craft.

But, as you've noted, the crafting UI is just a little bit broken.