# Can I get new crafting recipes from the trainer?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In The Old Republic, my main character has the armourmech crew skill. When I initially picked up the crew skill, the armourmech trainer offered me some crafting recipes, six of them.

Since that initial contact there've never been any new recipes available from the trainer whenever I've visited, all the new armour recipes I've got have either been learned from reverse engineering items I've created from those recipes, or from loot drops.

I seem to have out-levelled all of the initial recipes, and the reverse-engineered versions of those, too (shown by the grey number beside the recipes according to this [previous answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44966/263)) and am only getting the crafting XP from the handful of loot-drop recipes I've got.

I'm in the 20s level-wise, and in the  60s for armormech skill is that what's limiting me, do I need to get my level or armoursmith skill up higher before the trainer will offer me anything? Or is there no point to me going back to a trainers, and should I instead be relying on reverse-engineer/loot drops/GTN for stronger, more powerful armour recipes, and the trainer provided ones were only to start me off on my path?

Comment: I don't think grey means you've learned everything from reverse-engineering the items, just that the actual act of crafting them won't gain you any crafting skill.

Comment: @MatthewRead Sorry, probably wasn't quite clear in what I said, but I meant that the learnt items were showing grey, and also the reverse-engineered versions of those were showing grey too, so I wasb't getting skillpoints for crafting either the original or reverse-engineered versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you visit a crafting trainer, by default you only see the items you can craft with your current crafting skill. So, new items will appear there when your crafting skill reaches higher level.

But you can let it show all schematics (including those that you can't craft yet) by choosing "All" instead of "Trainable" in the dropdown in the upper right corner of the window. This way, you can find out what level of the crafting ability do you need to craft the better items.

[image: Biochem crafting trainer with the dropdown open]

In the screenshot above, you can see that I have chosen "All", so that even schematics that I can't craft yet (that require level ≥ 380) are visible.

Comment: I must have been bugged? I viewed All on the Armormech trainer on Fleet, and could see everything, then switched back to Trainable, and suddenly there was 2 pages worth of trainable items that I couldn't see before! (alternatively I'd at some point clicked that dropdown, set it to a category with nothing in, then the game defaulted to that, but surely I couldn't be that stupid, so I'm going with the face-saving bug option) Thanks!

Comment: Small correction: One cannot buy schematics you cannot learn yet. I've tested it yesterday on a live server. +1 for the screenshot, though.

Comment: @Sjoerd, you're right, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways to get recipes:

- Trained from your crafting trainer.
- Reverse engineered from your crafted items (this is how you learn 'blue' recipes, and from reverse engineering these blues, you get 'purple' recipes)
- Drops/Missions/Chests/GTN: you get items that are actually recipes that you can learn.

The majority of the recipes you'll have will be from 1+2: trainer + reverse engineering your crafted items

Answer (score 1):

Crafting trainers teach you more recipes as your skill increases (typically every 20 skill levels).

You need to go to the **armormech** trainer.  He's got the recipes for you to skill up.